# Blending one image onto another gives incorrect image because of alpha value

Tags: c++, image-processing

So I have an issue blending two images together dealing with transparency. I am using freetype here for generating the glyphs.I have a rather large codebase so I picked out the major portions of the code that are involved in the blending process.

This is the code i am using:

```
void TopDown(FT_Bitmap *bitmap, ... )
{
        .....
        .....

        for (int srcY=0; srcY < bitmap->rows; srcY++, destLine += textureWidth, srcLine += bitmap->pitch)
        {
            unsigned char *currSrc = srcLine;
            unsigned int *currDest = destLine;
            for (int srcX=0; srcX < bitmap->width; srcX++, currSrc++)
            {
                unsigned char alpha = *currSrc * textA / 255;
                if (currDest >= dest && currDest < destMax)
                {
                    unsigned int destR = (textR * alpha + bgR * (255-alpha))/255;
                    unsigned int destG = (textG * alpha + bgG * (255-alpha))/255;
                    unsigned int destB = (textB * alpha + bgB * (255-alpha))/255;

                    unsigned int as = alpha;
                    *currDest = makeColor(destR, destG, destB, alpha);
                }
                currDest++;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: *"However the blocks around the character are fully transparent ( you can see through them) why is this happening"*  Because the alpha channel of the texture is 0.0 at that parts? Try something like `textA = 255 - textA` or `textA = (texA==0) ? 255 : textA` for debug reasons.

Comment: @Rabbid76. I added `textA = 255 - textA` after `unsigned int textA = (textColor & 0xff000000) >> 24;` is that what you meant ?

Comment: @Rabbid76 doing that the transparency of the text is lost and it looks like this https://ibb.co/fe9qBK

Comment: @Scheff just incase you could open this link the image looks like this. https://ibb.co/fe9qBK . The transparency of the text is lost in this case which is incorrect. apart from that the background of the blocks is still transparent. Nothing changed only the opacity of the text is lost

Comment: Are you sure the "Hello" image is correct? Looks like there is no transparency outside the characters. In that case the blending is actually ok.

Comment: @Germán I am sorry but I am not sure what you mean by is the image correct ? The image looks fine to me for example the letter 'e' has full transparency around it which is incorrect. It should have grey around it.

Comment: @Scheff let me try `textA = 255 - textR` and post the result back

Comment: So, you want text on background rectangles? From my experience, text output has no background rectangles (regardless of background color, brush setting, or whatever). If I needed such (e.g. for labeling 3D rendering in a post-paintEvent) I determine bounding rectangle of text and paint a respective rectangle before. (Sorry, I couldn't open your alternative links as well. May be, I shouldn't discuss about painting when I'm effectively blind...) ;-)

Comment: I am getting the same result https://ibb.co/fe9qBK

Comment: I have problems with your `char* sourcePtr[]` (seems RGBA) and your `makeColor` func (seems to pack into 'int' ABGR), Can you clarify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets break this line `unsigned char alpha = *currSrc * textA / 255` in to two lines:

```
unsigned char alpha = *currSrc;
alpha = alpha * textA / 255;
```

This is actually taking the red component. You have to skip 3 bytes to get the alpha value:

```
unsigned char alpha = *currSrc + 3;
alpha = alpha * textA / 255;
```

You don't really need that though. Just find all the black pixels and set their alpha values to zero. Make sure text color is not black. You can use `0x00000001` for text color, this will set it apart from black background.

```
void TopDown(...)
{
    ...
    for(...)
    {
        ...
        for(...)
        {
            ...
            unsigned char r = *currSrc + 0;
            unsigned char g = *currSrc + 1;
            unsigned char b = *currSrc + 2;
            unsigned char alpha = 128; //or 255 or whatever
            if(currDest >= dest && currDest < destMax)
            {
                if(r || g || b)
                {
                    //non-black pixels get alpha value
                    *currDest = makeColor(r, g, b, alpha);
                }
                else
                {
                    //black pixels get zero alpha
                    *currDest = 0;
                }
            }
            currDest++;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you just have to draw over the background bitmap. No blending is necessary if the right paint function is used. The background will appear as transparent. To manually blend the colors:

```
unsigned char blend2(unsigned char m, unsigned char n, unsigned char alpha)
{
    float i = (float)n;
    float j = (float)m;
    float a = (float)alpha;

    j *= a / 255.0f; //you can skip this step

    int color = (int)((i + j)/2);
    return (unsigned char)color;
}

void blendBitmap(...)
{
    ...
    for (int line=0; line < copyHeight; line++)
    {
        T *destPtr = destBitmap->line(line+destRow) + 4*destCol;
        unsigned char *sourcePtr = sourceBitmap->line(line+srcRow) + 4*srcCol;
        if(destPtr && sourcePtr)
        {
            for (int col=0; col < copyWidth; col++, destPtr += 4, sourcePtr += 4)
            {
                unsigned char alpha = sourcePtr[3];
                destPtr[0] = blend2(destPtr[0], sourcePtr[0], alpha);
                destPtr[1] = blend2(destPtr[1], sourcePtr[1], alpha);
                destPtr[2] = blend2(destPtr[2], sourcePtr[2], alpha);
            }
        }
    }
}
```